# How to replace dot with a comma in the number

Tags: javascript, replace, webflow

Hey dear Stackoverflow community,
I have a JS code that calculates various values ​​based on an input value. It is output with a dot, but it should be displayed with a comma.

How can I customize the code for this?

```
<script>
var input = document.getElementById("invest_input-1");
input.oninput = function() {

var out = ((input.value * 0.38));
document.getElementById('invest_output_result-1').innerHTML = out.toFixed(2);
var out = ((input.value * 0.032));
document.getElementById('invest_output_result-2').innerHTML = out.toFixed(2);
var out = ((input.value * 0.03));
document.getElementById('invest_output_result-3').innerHTML = out.toFixed(2);
var out = ((input.value * 0.13));
document.getElementById('invest_output_result-4').innerHTML = out.toFixed(2);
      
};
</script>
```

Thank you so much!
Kind regards, Fabian

Comment: Are you looking for [`toLocaleString`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```js
out.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the user's locale:

```js
new Intl.NumberFormat().format(3500)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat#basic_usage